# Excel VBA Loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to creating VBA macros. I recorded the macro below, but I need this done for 18 other worksheets in the workbook. I do not know how to create a loop. Can it be done from this recorded macro? Sorry for the long code. Again this code is used on 18 other worksheets and am unsure how to create a loop.

```
Sheets("C3 CONW INW OPIS_CMA").Select
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSTRIK"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PRECID"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "P"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A26").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PEXCH"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C2:C26").Select
Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PQTY"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PCTYM"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PFC"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PACCT"

Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PPRTCP"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSUBTY"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSBUS"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H23"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H2:H23").Select
Columns("I:I").Select
Range("I240").Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PBS"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I23"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("I2:I23").Select
```

Again sorry for the format of the code.

Comment: It seems like  you have at least 3 separate questions in here. Can you take the [tour] and read up on [ask], then try re-framing your question to address only one particular problem (it's OK to ask multiple questions, separately, but generally could avoid combining 3 or 4 separate problems into a single question).

Comment: [How to avoid using Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: [How to find the last used cell in a range/column/sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: [For...Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/fornext-statement) loop documentation

Comment: [For Each ... Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/for-eachnext-statement) loop documentation

Comment: So, you need to 1) Loop over each Worksheet in the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` collection, and 2) modify your code in such a way that it finds the appropriate "last row" for any column/etc that you need to operate against. For bonus points: 3) refactor the code to avoid `Select` and `ActiveCell` :)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit, and put it into a sub which takes a worksheet as its argument. I then made another sub which loops through all the worksheets of the workbook the code resides in, and makes the changes specified.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call fix_stuff_in_the_sheet(ws)
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub fix_stuff_in_the_sheet(ws As Worksheet)

    ws.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSTRIK"
    ws.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "PRECID"
    ws.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "P"
    ws.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ws.Range("A2:A26").FormulaR1C1 = "PEXCH"

    ws.Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "7"
    ws.Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C26"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ws.Columns("N:O").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    ws.Columns("D:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("E:E").Cut
    ws.Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ws.Columns("I:I").Cut
    ws.Columns("K:K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    ws.Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "PQTY"
    ws.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "PCTYM"
    ws.Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "PFC"
    ws.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "PACCT"
    ws.Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "PPRTCP"

    ws.Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSUBTY"
    ws.Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSBUS"
    ws.Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    ws.Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H23"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ws.Range("I240").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ws.Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "PBS"
    ws.Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    ws.Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I23"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

If you don't want the code to be performed on all the sheets in your workbook, you need to figure out a way for the first function to only be called with the sheets you want as an argument.

There is still some superfluous code in the subs I post here, e.g. you first autofill range A2:A26 with the letter P, but then later overwrites that with PEXCH. I'll leave it to you to weed out this though.